# Output of one request used as a parameter in next request using Asyncio + Aiohttp

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm new to Async programming, Asyncio, Aiohttp world.

I have multiple requests where - output of 1st request is being used as a parameter in 2nd request.

So far I have tried this much -

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def get_response(session, url, params):
    async with session.get(url=url, params=params) as response:
        response = await response.json()
        return response['output']


async def main():

    tasks = []

    url = "https://example.api.com/"

    url_1 = url + 'path_1'
    url_2 = url + 'path_2'

    params = {'name': "Hello"}

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        a1 = get_response(session, url_1, params)
        tasks.append(a1)

        params = {'name': a1}
        b1 = get_response(session, url_2, params)
        tasks.append(b1)

        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

        print(responses)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I'm getting this error which is obvious -

```
TypeError("Invalid variable type: value should be str, int or float, got <coroutine object get_response at 0x00000000037FA6C0> of type <class 'coroutine'>")
```

So how do I pass the output of 1st request and not the coroutine object to the 2nd request -

```
params = {'name': a1}
b1 = get_response(session, url_2, params)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm curious if my answer helped with your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result of the first coroutine is needed for the second one, then you cannot run both coroutines in parallel, you will need to *await* the response of the first one. For example:

```
async def get_both(session, url_1, url_2, params_1):
    a1 = await get_response(session, url_1, params_1)
    params_2 = {'name': a1}
    b1 = await get_response(session, url_2, params_2)
    return a1, b1  # or just b1 if you don't need a1
```

Your `main()` would then look like this:

```
async def main():
    url = "https://example.api.com/"
    url_1 = url + 'path_1'
    url_2 = url + 'path_2'
    params = {'name': "Hello"}

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        responses = await get_both(session, url_1, url_2, params)
        print(responses)
```

Of course, you don't get parallel fetching, but that's a direct consequence of the fact that one request depends on the result of the other. What you could easily do is parallelize multiple instances of `get_both` - e.g. if `url_1` and `url_2` were lists, you could do this:

```
async def main():
    url_list_1 = [...]
    url_list_2 = [...]
    params = {'name': "Hello"}

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        coros = [get_both(session, url_1, url_2, params)
                 for url_1, url_2 in zip(url_list_1, url_list_2)]
        all_responses = await asyncio.gather(*coros)
        print(all_responses)
```